# firing of two div make the third div to go display none

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying something like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if(div1)&&(div2)==display:none
{
    div3=display:none;
}    
else
{
    div3=display:block;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a jsfiddle?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((".div1")css('display')=="none")
{
    (".div3").show();
}
else
{
    (".div3").show();
}
```

Comment: Arent the selectors specified here wrong. The question has only elements which the OP has pre-stored in variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<div id="first">1</div>
<div id="second">2</div>
<div id="third" style="display:none">3</div>
```

script

```
if(!($("#first").is(":visible")&&$("#second").is(":visible")))
{
$("#third").hide();
}
else
{
$("#third").show();
}
```